# How to control IP ranges of Network Manager's hotspots?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, ip

A server has two WiFi interfaces, both configured via Network Manager to be hotspots.

Connected clients get IPs in ranges 10.42.0.0/24 and 10.42.1.0/24 (AFAICS via `dnsmasq` invoked by NM). I need to be able to assign a specific range to a specific interface. Unfortunately, Network Manager assigns them unpredictably (so `wlan0` may get 10.42.0.0 today and 10.42.1.0 tomorrow; then `wlan1` gets the remaining range) which messes up my `iptables` because the routing rules are different for these interfaces.

I tried `dhcp-range=` option in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` (which wasn't present as NM configures `dnsmasq` via command line) and some other ideas but can't find a workable solution.

Any thoughts on how I can control which IP range gets assigned to which interface?

Comment: Why didn't dhcp-range not work?  Just ignored your settings?

Comment: I used "`dhcp-range=wlan0,10.42.0.2,10.42.0.253,72h`" in `dnsmasq.conf` (and similar for `wlan1`). That did not have any effect. I presume Network Manager runs `dnsmasq` via cmd-line which takes precedence.

Comment: Also tried placing `dnsmasq.conf` in `/etc` and in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d` but DHCP ranges are still assigned unpredictably. Forgot to mention that it is 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Have you tried `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local` and then `sudo restart network-manager`.

Comment: yes (to no avail)

Comment: `ps ax | grep dnsmasq` shows me that Network Manager invokes `dnsmasq` twice: `/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file --no-hosts --keep-in-foreground --bind-interfaces --except-interface=lo --clear-on-reload --strict-order --listen-address=10.42.0.1 --dhcp-range=10.42.0.10,10.42.0.254,60m --dhcp-option=option:router,10.42.0.1 --dhcp-lease-max=50 --pid-file=/var/run/nm-dnsmasq-wlan0.pid --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d` I cannot figure out why this pair changes randomly after I reboot or do `sudo service network-manager restart`. The randomness appears to come from Network Manager.

Comment: Also from cmd-line it's clear that `dnsmasq` should use `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d` which I also tried but that didn't help. Could it be that `dnsmasq` follows cmd-line (supplied by NM) and ignores the config file?

Comment: Since you have two entries for the same fields, one in the cmdline and one in the config, it certainly is going to cause confusion.  I would try to remove it from the cmdline start if it's being added by Network Manager and hopefully allow the config to place the values.  I don't use Network Manager, so I'm not much help.

Answer (score 10):

After hours of trying different solutions, I was finally able to specify a subnet for a Hotspot connection using Network Manager and then set a manual ip on the client device for a sort of static ip. None of the dnsmasq/dhcp methods work with Network Manager. You have to edit the Network Manager connection file. These files are generated for each connection in the following directory:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

I believe that when you create a Hotspot, a new connection file is created and is named Hotspot. You need to edit this file. Make sure you are editing the Hotspot connection file or this will not work! Change/add the following lines under the section `[ipv4]` to set a subnet. Make sure it has the line `method=shared` and use whatever ip address you want for `address1=` and NetworkManager will issue all connecting devices an ip in the same subnet. The format for this line is `address1=ip/subnetmask,gateway`. Gateway should be the same as the ip. Here is what the `[ipv4]` section should look like:

```
[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared
address1=192.168.125.1/24,192.168.125.1
```

Once you have this completed, save the file and run the following to restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Now your connected devices should be issued an ip address under the same subnet as the ip you entered. In this example it would be 192.168.125.x.

To get a static ip, do that on the client side device. Set a manual ip for this hotspot connection under same subnet, using the same subnet mask and gateway that were entered in the Hotspot connection file.

Here is my whole Hotspot connection file for reference:

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=14032jb9-43c6-41c6-8d56-8b6b0f7xcce9
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan0
permissions=
secondaries=
timestamp=1486816539

[wifi]
mac-address=7C:84:DB:62:7B:3F
mac-address-blacklist=
mac-address-randomization=0
mode=ap
seen-bssids=7C:84:DB:62:7B:3F;
ssid=yournetworkname

[wifi-security]
group=
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=
proto=
psk=yourpassword

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared
address1=192.168.125.1/24,192.168.125.1

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=ignore
```

Documentation on this setting in Network Manager can be read here:

https://people.freedesktop.org/~lkundrak/nm-docs/nm-settings.html

Table 36. ipv4 setting

Key Name: method

Value Type: string

Default Value:

Value Description: IP configuration method. NMSettingIP4Config and NMSettingIP6Config both support "auto", "manual", and "link-local". See the subclass-specific documentation for other values. In general, for the "auto" method, properties such as "dns" and "routes" specify information that is added on to the information returned from automatic configuration. The "ignore-auto-routes" and "ignore-auto-dns" properties modify this behavior. For methods that imply no upstream network, such as "shared" or "link-local", these properties must be empty. For IPv4 method "shared", the IP subnet can be configured by adding one manual IPv4 address or otherwise 10.42.x.0/24 is chosen.

Most important part:

> For IPv4 method "shared", the IP subnet can be configured by adding
>   one manual IPv4 address or otherwise 10.42.x.0/24 is chosen.

Comment: Good answer, helped me, upvoted. One issue though: NetworkManager seems to rewrite its connection files from time to time, especially the Hotspot connection when it sees a new client ssid. If, between your change to the address, and the service restart, a new SSID connects, your changes will be lost. Better stop NetworkManager first, then apply the change, then start it.

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the used IPv4 subnet by configuring one manual address, like

`nmcli connection modify $SHARED_NAME ipv4.addresses 192.168.2.5/24`

It's documented in `man nm-settings`, see ipv4.method.

/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d is for using dnsmasq as DNS plugin, not for your use case of connection sharing.
For that, it is instead /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d -- at least in recent versions of NM.
But you shouldn't need that.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. AFAICS setting an IP is incompatible with `ipv4.method shared`: NM fails to set the gateway and DNS properly in this situation. And manual control is impossible - `nmcli` refuses to accept `ipv4.dns` in `ipv4.method shared` mode. (I am pretty sure I tried that before by directly modifying `address1=` in `NetworkManager/system-connections` - the result was the same: IPs could be set but gateway/DNS were not.) Any ideas?

Comment: Manual [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/nm-settings.5.html) confirms this: _Addresses cannot  be used with the 'shared', 'link-local', or 'disabled' methods as addressing is either automatic or disabled_ and _If `shared` is specified ... the interface is assigned an address in the 10.42.x.1/24 range..._.

Comment: True, trusty has 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.1, which is very old by now. Works since [0.9.10](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/?id=32a001f526c182fa70ede92ffc360112eb7fe9c6), as also documented in recent [manual](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings.html#nm-settings.property.ipv4.method). I don't understand why you talk about `ipv4.dns`, do you mean `ipv4.addresses`?

Comment: I tried to set DNS via `ipv4.dns` because `nmcli connection modify $SHARED_NAME ipv4.addresses 192.168.2.5/24` leaves all clients connected to the hotspots without any gateway and DNS settings. Setting address in `shared` mode should not work at all but, instead, it creates non-functioning hotspots. What I really need is some control of "x" in 10.42.x.1/24 ranges used by NM (as it sets "x" randomly).

Comment: As said, you cannot configure the chosen subnet with version 0.9.8. It works with later version by configuring one manual address. You say it doesn't work, but it's not clear from your comment why. NM on Ubuntu 14.04 would not allow you to do what you want.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 16.04 with NM version 1.2.2. Let me clarify my _incompatible with `ipv4.method shared` statement_. The `ipv4.addresses` is accepted and IP gets assigned to the right interface. However, after that change all clients connected to the hotspot stop receiving sensible gateway and DNS settings. So it makes things worse - nothing works anymore (compared to 50:50 chance currently when 10.42.0.0/24 and 10.42.1.0/24 are randomly assigned to interfaces). Is there any evidence or a working example of successfully using `ipv4.method shared` with `ipv4.addresses`?

Comment: Actually, it appears that changing the `ipv4.addresses` to use a single address (I used `10.42.0.1` and `10.42.1.1` instead of a range like `192.168.2.5/24`) helps. Let me test it a bit more thoroughly - I'll confirm if it does. Your reference to documentation on gnome.org was very useful. Thanks a million, thaller!

Answer (score 1):

The following appears to work OK - these commands force Network Manager to assign selected DHCP ranges to Wifi access points (10.42.0.x to wifiname1; 10.42.1.x to wifiname2):

`nmcli connection modify wifiname1 ipv4.addresses 10.42.0.1

nmcli connection modify wifiname2 ipv4.addresses 10.42.1.1`

Note: `wifinameN (N=1/2)` correspond to files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.

Answer (score 0):

In [`nm-dnsmasq-manager.c`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/blob/main/src/core/dnsmasq/nm-dnsmasq-manager.c) we can see

`listen_address = nm_ip4_config_get_first_address(ip4_config);`

(presumably this is `ipv4.addresses` in the NetworkManager `connection`)

which gets passed to the utilities [`nm-dnsmasq-utils.c`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/blob/main/src/core/dnsmasq/nm-dnsmasq-utils.c) as `addr`

We can see `addr` gets coerced into a `dhcp-range`  with some default "smart rules" using the `addr` and its `netmask` ... meaning if you choose `192.168.0.0/22` you'll get server as 192.168.0.1 (it fixes using the network address) and then it will also pair down your mask to be less, say `/24`. After creating `first` and `last` this gets passed to

```c
nm_strv_ptrarray_add_string_printf(cmd, "--dhcp-range=%s,%s,60m", first, last);
```